# spfx rest api read image column

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

I am trying to read image column in spfx using rest and nojS. THe site modern. I am unable to get the exact url. There are other properties like server relative url is returned. However is it possible to get the image and then it can be bound to image control?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert json data into objects(My image column name is img).

```
var obj = eval('(' + data.d.img + ')');
$("#img").attr("src", obj.serverRelativeUrl);
```

I test with js, It should be similar in SPFX, you can refer to it.
Full test code:

```
<img id="img">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('test3')/items(17)",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var obj = eval('(' + data.d.img + ')');
                $("#img").attr("src", obj.serverRelativeUrl);
                $("#img").attr("style", "width:50px;height:50px;")
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Test result:
[image]